# How to configure custom ldap based authentication for GKE nodes?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

We have a private GKE cluster and users want to SSH into the worker nodes, currently we inject their SSH' keys to enable login or ask them to use gcloud compute ssh command. Trying to understand if there is anyway to configure custom LDAP, so that we can avoid  key based authentication and use LDAP. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions as well, Thanks!

Comment: Is key management really the issue more than the need to use external LDAP?  Can you add a few more details on what you mean by "we inject their SSH keys"?  And are these users members of your GCP Org or external users?

Comment: Hi @GariSingh - By "injecting the SSH keys" I meant adding the SSH public key in the GCP project metadata, and these users are internal and part of GCP Org.

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize OS Login with GKE now which does what you need: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/enable-oslogin

I'm assuming your LDAP users are already in Cloud Identity due to some syncing happening between LDAP and Cloud Identity.

From the docs: Once you have enabled the OS Login organization policy, you no longer need to manage SSH keys to make authorization decisions. OS Login moves authorization management to Identity and Access Management. To manage SSH access to nodes, use OS Login. For more details, see [Setting up OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access).

Comment: Thanks @Sam Stoelinga for the suggestion, will explore more on this!